# How do you open a tin of corned beef with a broken lid?

Tags: food, container

[image: broken lid can]

So horrible i cant eat any food. Need to fix now

Answer (score 6):

Run around the big end with a conventional can opener (a P38 type will work best for the short radius corners).

Answer (score 0):

I saw a video once of opening a can by rubbing the top on an abrasive surface - cement floor, for example - you wear down the edges where the top is sealed to the bottom and eventually you can peel off the top. I'd say this is a hard way to go, you have to be pretty hungry to use this method - it was a survival method, not for routine use.

Comment: And you'd possibly wind up with metal shavings in the food. So be careful!